# Then find the range of m.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that there are real constants $a,b,c,d$ such that the identity
$$Mx^2+2xy+y^2=(ax+by)^2+(cx+dy)^2$$ holds for all $x,y$ in the set of real numbers,  what is the range of $M$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Can you find some $M$ for which it works?  Can you find some $M$ for which it does not work?

Comment: Yes... If M less then zero ...it will not work

Comment: Ok.  Can you find some $M$ for which it does work?

Comment: Wait.. Let me think

Comment: For M=1 it will work

Comment: Can you see how to use the construction for $M=1$ to solve a whole range of examples?   If you keep going on these lines you should, fairly quickly, see what the "good" range of $M$ is.  Once you see that, I bet you'll be able to finish quickly.

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: Well, presumably you found $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$ that gave you this identity with $M=1$, yes?  So work from there.  What if we take $M=\frac 12$?  Can you solve it then? What about $M=2$?  A few examples really should tell you what the answer is, after which proving it is really not that difficult.

Comment: For M=1/2 it is not possible... But i cant find the whole range

Comment: it's good you managed $\frac 12$.  What about $2$?

Comment: It can possible

Comment: What are the values $(a,b,c,d)$ for which you get $M=2$?  Can you see how to generalize this to $M=3$?  $M=75$?

Comment: At some point soon you should be able to at least guess the answer here.  That's big progress! it's always easier to prove that an idea is correct than it is to attack a totally unknown situation.  And if you find a counterexample to your guess...well, that's new information and it might lead you to make a better guess.

Comment: (-1,-1,-1,0),(-1,-1,1,0),(1,1,10)

Comment: Good, so have you made a guess as to the answer yet?  Can you test it?

Comment: May be M greater or equal to 1

Comment: But i cant prove

Comment: That's a solid guess. l'll post something below.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying out the right hand gives us $$Mx^2+xy+y^2=(a^2+c^2)x^2+2xy(ab+cd)+(b^2+d^2)y^2$$  from which we see that we want to simultaneously solve $$a^2+c^2=M\quad \quad ab+cd=1\quad \quad b^2+d^2=1$$

Apply [Cauchy Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) to the vectors $\vec v = (a,c)$ and $\vec u = (b,d)$.   We deduce that $$(ab+cd)^2≤(a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)$$ which in our case yields $$1≤M$$

Now, if we have $M≥1$ we can simply take $$(a,b,c,d)=\left(\sqrt M,\, \frac 1{\sqrt M}, \,0,\, \sqrt {1-\frac 1M}\right)$$

(noting that $M≥1$ implies that the square root expression for $d$ does give a real number).

So we see that the final answer is $$\boxed {M≥1}$$

Comment: Thank you very very much